# pyspark parsing nested json ignoring all the key

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the single-line JSON. trying to parse and store using Pyspark

Raw file content of 'path.json'

```
{"number": 34, "tool": {"name": "temp", "guid": null, "version": "2.13:1"}}
```

code in pyspark

```
>>> df = spark.read.options(multiline=True, dropFieldIfAllNull=False).json('path.json')
>>> df.show(1,False)
+------+--------------------+
|number|tool                |
+------+--------------------+
|34    |{null, temp, 2.13.1}|
+------+--------------------+


>>> df.select('tool').show(1,False)
+--------------------+
|tool                |
+--------------------+
|{null, temp, 2.13:1}|
+--------------------+

>>>
```

if you see the structure of the key "tool" is `{null, temp, 2.13:1}` and when I am storing this to the database it is stored in the same way. However, I want to keep it in the proper key-value format like `{"name": "temp", "guid": null, "version": "2.13;1"}`.

Storing to database

```
df2 = df_with_ts.withColumn('tool', col('tool').cast('string'))

df2.write \
    .format("") \
    .option("url", url) \
    .option("dbtable", "temp") \
    .option("tempdir", "path") \
    .mode("append") \
    .save()
```

I want this to store like

```
{"name": "temp", "guid": null, "version": "2.13;1"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIU, what you need is to stringify the `tool` column, you can do that using the `to_json` or `concat` functions.

The `tool` column is already a `Struct` with key and value but packing  the Struct into string takes only the list of values.

**A more generic option to dump it as a json is to use `to_json`**

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_json

df.withColumn('toolStr', to_json('tool', options={"ignoreNullFields":False})).show(10, False)
```

```
+------+--------------------+----------------------------------------------+
|number|tool                |toolStr                                       |
+------+--------------------+----------------------------------------------+
|34    |{null, temp, 2.13:1}|{"guid":null,"name":"temp","version":"2.13:1"}|
+------+--------------------+----------------------------------------------+
```

**If you need a custom format while dumping the Struct, then you can use `concat` function**

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat, lit, when, isnull, col

df = spark.read.options(multiline=True, dropFieldIfAllNull=False).json('path.json')

df.withColumn('toolStr', concat(\
    lit('{"name": '), when(isnull('tool.name'), lit('""')).otherwise(col('tool.name')),\
    lit(', "guid": '), when(isnull('tool.guid'), lit('""')).otherwise(col('tool.guid')),\
    lit(', "version": '), when(isnull('tool.version'), lit('""')).otherwise(col('tool.version')), lit('}')\
)).show(1,False)
```

```
+------+--------------------+---------------------------------------------+
|number|tool                |toolStr                                      |
+------+--------------------+---------------------------------------------+
|34    |{null, temp, 2.13:1}|{"name": temp, "guid": "", "version": 2.13:1}|
+------+--------------------+---------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Yes the understanding the correct, I want to stringify the column but the tool is only the basic example to simplify the question, in reality, the schema for the JSON is much more complex. we want to keep the field as it from raw for auditing purpose and want to parse other fields from json

Comment: @ankursingh1000 added a more generic option so you don't have to concatenate manually

Comment: Thanks, This was the solution I was expecting. But if you also explain the logic of why that was happening it would be great.

Comment: The tool column is already a Struct with key and value, but dumping the Struct into string takes values as a list without keys